# Why do for loop executes before Jquery Selector in this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the code below the `for` loop executes always first, the jQuery selector comes later. But I want to run this for loop after changing the value of the selected sliders.

```
$('div[name="FirstSliderselector"]').slider('value', $("#MasterSlider").slider("value"));
var FirstSliders = $('div[name="FirstSliderselector"]');
for (var i = 0; i < FirstSliders.length; i++) {
     console.log('for loop executed');
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it does? doesn't look like it would do

Comment: Clarification, do you want to run this `for` loop after the Master Slider changes or after the First Slide Selector changes, or both?

Comment: @DerekHenderson after `$('div[name="FirstSliderselector"]')` changes. It changes only after executing the following for loop. Why Javascript behaves like this in this context?

Comment: This is correct JS behaviour.  Otherwise, events like the slider would be blocking execution of the rest of your code, which is not desirable.

Comment: @DerekHenderson But, if i make a delay in the for loop, Js waits  to complete the for loop. Won't this block the execution of those events which doesn't need the for loop to be executed?

Comment: @DerekHenderson Is there any other way that I could change the value of `$('div[name="FirstSliderselector"])`

Comment: You can change it manually by moving the slider handle or you can change it programmatically using `.value()`.

Comment: @KiranramchandranP, I think I now see what you're trying to do.  You want to set the value of 'FirstSliderSelector' somewhere programmatically, and you also want to bind a change event to the slider.  Correct?

Comment: @DerekHenderson Really, I have a method which uses the values of `$('div[name="FirstSliderselector"])`. Before executing this method I want to change the value of `$('div[name="FirstSliderselector"])`. But when I tried, the value changed only after executing the method. I don't want to get a change or slide event while doing this.

Comment: @DerekHenderson I can't use the function at 'slide:'. I already assigned something to do inside this function. I don't want to insert seperate functions for each sliders. In fact, I have a lot of dynamically created sliders in my page, which uses the same slider creating call for creating all sliders.(by varying the ids).

Comment: @DerekHenderson I want to change it programatically. But can't use the change event directly.

Comment: The `.slider` method seems to be asynchronous? Show us what it does.

Comment: @KiranramchandranP can you create a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/ to demonstrate the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guaranteed to run the for loop after the slider assignment...

```
var FirstSliders = $('div[name="FirstSliderselector"]'),
    MastSliderValue = $("#MasterSlider").slider("value");

function updateSliders(){
    FirstSliders.slider('value', MastSliderValue);
}

$.when(
    updateSliders()        
).done(
    function(){
        for (var i = 0; i < FirstSliders.length; i++) {
             console.log('for loop executed');
        }
    }
);
```

Thanks for -1 on first attempt guys ;) new to this.

Answer (score 4):

**Edited to reflect new understanding of the question**

<s>What you want to do is pass a callback function for the change event, like this:</s>

What I now understand is that you want to trigger a change event when you change the value of the slider.  You set the value programmatically somewhere with:

```
$('div[name="FirstSliderselector"]').slider('value', $('#MasterSlider').slider('value'));
```

In order for your `for` loop to execute after you've done this, you will need to have bound a change event to the slider, like this:

```
$('div[name="FirstSliderselector"]').slider({
    change: function (event, ui) {
        var firstSliders = $('div[name="FirstSliderselector"]'),
            i;
        for (i = 0; i < firstSliders.length; i += 1) {
            console.log(ui.value);
        }
    }
});
```

You can also do it like this:

```
$('div[name="FirstSliderselector"]').on('slidechange', function (event, ui) {
    var firstSliders = $('div[name="FirstSliderselector"]'),
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < firstSliders.length; i += 1) {
        console.log(ui.value);
    }
});
```

If you want to make sure this is only triggered when the value change is done programmatically and not after the slider slides, your callback function becomes this:

```
function (event, ui) {
    if (!event.originalEvent) {
        var firstSliders = $('div[name="FirstSliderselector"]'),
            i;
        for (i = 0; i < firstSliders.length; i += 1) {
            console.log(ui.value);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, if none of these satisfy your needs, there is always, as suggested by Chris GW Green, the when-done construct:

```
$.when($('div[name="FirstSliderselector"]').slider('value', $('#MasterSlider').slider('value'));).then(function () {
    var firstSliders = $('div[name="FirstSliderselector"]'),
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < firstSliders.length; i += 1) {
        console.log('for loop executed');
    }
});
```

Comment: It will only trigger when you change the value of First Slider.  This is why I asked for clarification above.  If you want the value of First Slider to change when you change Master Slider, that's a bit different.  Let me know.

Comment: I want to change the value of `div[name="FirstSliderselector"]` first. I want to execute another method in this for loop which uses the new value set to `div[name="FirstSliderselector"]`. But in my code the for loop executes first.

Comment: You didn't specify you needed the value of the slider in your callback!  I've edited my answer to show how you can access the value.

Comment: BTW, you should check out the jQuery Slider API (http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/).

Comment: @KiranramchandranP, surely one of the options in my (edited) answer must do what you are hoping for, right?